# Spring Integration @ServiceActivator or @Bean definition to support @Profile usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have question about usage of service activator and its definition way.

I have 3 service activatiors that are taking messages from different input channels and sends them to single output channel. This is designed in "dev" environment...

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "irregularMessageChannel_1", outputChannel = "combinedChannel")
public String handlerSite1(String data, @Header(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS) String connectionId) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("content received from : {} data : {} ", connectionId, data);
    return data;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "irregularMessageChannel_2", outputChannel = "combinedChannel")
public String handlerSite2(String data, @Header(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS) String connectionId) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("content received from : {} data : {} ", connectionId, data);
    return data;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "irregularMessageChannel_3", outputChannel = "combinedChannel")
public String handlerSite3(String data, @Header(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS) String connectionId) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("content received from : {} data : {} ", connectionId, data);
    return data;
}
```

But in prod or preprod environment i need to add one more... so i checked to use @Profile annotation with  @ServiceActivator like below

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "irregularMessageChannel_X", outputChannel = "combinedChannel")
@Profile("prod")
public String handlerSiteX(String data, @Header(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS) String connectionId) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("content received from : {} data : {} ", connectionId, data);
    return data;
}
```

But as far as i understood, @Profile is not working with @ServiceActivator and it requires @Bean Definition too.

But

When i googled it, it is written that if i use @Bean definition, i should return MessageHandler... I simply create MessageHandler and return it...

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "irregularMessageChannel_X",outputChannel = "combinedChannel")
@Profile("prod")
public MessageHandler handlerSiteX() {
    MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled())
                log.debug("content received from : {} data : {} ", message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS), message);
        }
    };
    return handler ;
}
```

Question Part - 1

Now i have question that how can i send my message to output channel like i use in @ServiceActivator ?

Together with @Bean annotation it is not allowed to use outputChannel attribute in @ServiceActivator. Or is there any way to use @Profile annotation without @Bean but with @ServiceActivator ?

> EDIT

Question Part - 2

Also should i create input channel by my self ? If ı use @Bean definition or is it created automatically like in @ServiceActivator ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `@Profile` on `@Bean`s, not on `@ServiceActivator` methods that are in a `@Bean`.

See [Annotations on @Bean Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans).

Your `@Bean` should look like this:

```java
@Bean
@Profile("...")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "...")
public MessageHandler profiledHandler() {
    ServiceActivatingHandler handler = new ServiceActivatingHandler(myServiceBean, 
        "handlerSiteX");
    handler.setOutputChannelName("combinedChannel");
    return handler;
{
```

The output channel goes on the handler; yes, the input channel will be created if needed.

Comment: Typically the `@ServiceActivator` is defined in some `@Componenet`. You can use the `@Profile` on that class and its bean going to be skipped (together with that `@ServiceActivator`) if profile is not active. It is really better to design your project the way when you don't mix test and prod code in the same class.

Comment: Thank you Gary and @Artem, i will go on and try your suggestion.